# Remove special characters and numbers from column R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df which looks like this -

```
df <- data.frame(c = c('X.Int.2', 'BI', 'X.Int..4', 'BI.4', 'X.Int.6'),
                 d = sample(1:5, replace=T))
```

I am trying to remove all special characters, the 'X' and the numbers from col d.

I have tried

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = gsub("\\s[0-9()]+", '', c))
```

and

```
df %>%
    mutate(c = str_extract_all(c, "field:[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

Neither throw up an errors, but the first doesn't change the df and the second empties the column.

I'm clearly missing something obvious.

I'm hoping for -

```
c<-c('Int', "BI', 'Int', 'BI', 'Int')
```

Comment: Sorry - should have added as.data.frame!

Comment: No need for `cbind` do `df<-data.frame(c,d)`

Comment: Sorry, these are errors with my example, not my actual df (which in longer), I'm not sure how to replicate it fully here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove X. and digits

```
str_remove_all(df$c, "[X.]|[:digit:]")
#> [1] "Int" "BI"  "Int" "BI"  "Int"
```

inside mutate:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(c = str_remove_all(c, "[X.]|[:digit:]"))
#>     c d
#> 1 Int 4
#> 2  BI 1
#> 3 Int 2
#> 4  BI 3
#> 5 Int 5
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can try with `gsub` :

```
gsub('[X.0-9]', '', df$c)
#> [1] "Int" "BI"  "Int" "BI"  "Int"
```

This removes character `"X"`, `"."` and numbers from `c` column.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `gsub`

```
gsub("[X.\\d+]", "", df$c, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Int" "BI"  "Int" "BI"  "Int"
```